# On a lighter note: 'Tis the season for Hats!

Tags: discussion, winterbash, hats

[Winterbash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is coming!* 'Tis the season of earning silly hats for your avatar to wear by achieving achievements in Stack usage. Not only are these achievements more "fun", off-kilter, and promote a sense of community festivity than the usual goals for getting badges, but they earn you hats. Some are secret criteria for secret hats, but the non-secret hat criteria are listed on the Winterbash 2014 site, for which you earn hats.

Did I mention there are hats.

So get your heads (or dice, abstract concepts, *other* hats, pets, or whatever your avatar displays) ready, because Winterbash starts December 15th (site time) and runs until January 5th. For those who are new to RPG.SE since the last Winterbash, the [Winterbash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) site and [FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq) should give you an idea of what to expect.

And should you have an unreasonable, irrational, ridiculous but totally **respected** hatred of hats, you can opt out and have a 100% hat-free holiday site experience.

* <strike>Site not yet live! But it is already alive in our hearts.</strike>

Comment: My avatar is fully prepped for hattage.

Comment: my avatar already has a hat :)

Comment: @waxeagle All the better for hat stacking!

Comment: I used to be a commensurate hat wearer, time to get back into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hatmas is over. The hats are gone. Go home! And [leave some feedback for what you want next year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246533/152515) if you want.

[image: here's to next year!]

Comment: There's the [[winterbash-2014\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2014) tag on Meta.SE for all our confusion-based needs. **Warning! Spoilers!** Avoid the secret hat–related questions if you don't want spoilers.

Comment: Nice edit. I approve.